# Replacing realloc (C --> C++)

Tags: c++, c, void-pointers, realloc

In an earlier question, I asked about typecasting pointers, but was directed to the better solution of using the C++ allocation system instead of mallocs. (I am converting some C code to C++)

However, I still have an issue with a similar function:

I changed:

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp); --> tmp = new char*[mtmp];
```

and

```
free(tmp) --> delete [] tmp;
```

However, what do I do with realloc in the following function:

```
char* space_getRndPlanet (void)
{
   int i,j;
   char **tmp;
   int ntmp;
   int mtmp;
   char *res;

   ntmp = 0;
   mtmp = CHUNK_SIZE;
   //tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * mtmp); <-- replaced with line below
   tmp = new char*[mtmp];
   for (i=0; i<systems_nstack; i++)
      for (j=0; j<systems_stack[i].nplanets; j++) {
         if(systems_stack[i].planets[j]->real == ASSET_REAL) {
            ntmp++;
            if (ntmp > mtmp) { /* need more space */
               mtmp += CHUNK_SIZE;
               tmp = realloc(tmp, sizeof(char*) * mtmp); <--- Realloc
            }
            tmp[ntmp-1] = systems_stack[i].planets[j]->name;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char**'|
```

EDIT 2:

Okay, the consensus I am getting is that I should ditch my current solution (which I am open to doing).

**Just to make sure that I am understanding correctly, do you guys mean that, instead of an array of pointers to objects, I should just have a vector containing the objects themselves?**

Comment: Well ignoring the fact that you are using realloc() incorrectly in the above piece of code. This is a weakness of C++ caused because objects have constructors/destructors. The problem is resolved by using vector rather than raw arrays.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C allows `void*` to be implicitly converted to any pointer.  C++ doesn't, so if you're using `realloc`, you have to cast the result to the appropriate type.

But more importantly, using `realloc` on a pointer returned by `new[]` is undefined behavior.  And there's no direct C++-style equivalent to `realloc`.

Your choices are, from least to most idiomatic:

- Stick to `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` and cast the pointers.
- Use `new[]` + `delete[]` instead of `realloc`
- Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of managing your own memory.

Comment: Plus you shouldn't be mixing new/delete and malloc/calloc/realloc/free memory allocation.

Comment: Technically you should use `delete[]` with `new[]`.

Answer (score 14):

This appears to be an unremarkable array that grows as needed.

Stop using explicit memory allocation, you almost certainly have no need of it. Use `std::vector` or another of the C++ standard library's dynamic containers that automatically grow as needed for you.

It also looks like you're using null-terminated C-style strings. Why not used `std::string` instead?

Comment: I'm converting some old C code, and learning as I go (not familiar with C much, just C++). So this might work.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ you should not be using arrays (even dynamically allocated).

This has been replaced with std::vector

In C:

```
char** tmp = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
free(tmp);

// And a correct version of realloc
char** alt = (char**)realloc(sizeof(char*) * newSize);
if (alt)
{
    // Note if realloc() fails then it returns NULL
    // But that does not mean the original object is deallocated.
    tmp = alt;
}
```

In C++

```
std::vector<char*>   tmp(size);

// No need for free (destructor does that).
tmp.resize(newSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/18311/

(In short - there's not really a C++ equivalent to `realloc`, but maybe you'd be better of using a `vector`?)

Comment: Could you explain to me what exactly realloc is doing here? Also, by replacing the current solution with vectors does this mean that, instead of a stack, i am using an array-like device (i.e. vector). I.e.: does this mean I should replace the current stack solution?

Comment: @Biosci3c You can also use a stack then. C++ defines both types in the standard template library. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Comment: @Biosci3c - realloc is creating a bigger memory space to hold the contents of what's in `tmp`, because the old space was filled up. Re-sizable C++ containers do this automatically for you. You can use a `stack` or a `vector`; both of them support "stack-like" operations (but the `vector` also supports random access, whereas the `stack` does not).

Comment: Also, in your current solution, `tmp` is not a stack, it is an array.

Comment: Realloc will try to resize the currently allocated memory block. If it can't (say, you're trying to enlarge it and there's another block in the way), it will allocate a new memory block, copy the pointer's content and return a new pointer to the structure. (The original pointer's not changed unless you do so). Given the nature of objects in C++ (deep copy vs shallow copy, for one), this kind of logic must be handled by the user since the compiler can't know how things need to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

Realloc doesnt reallly care about calling constructors, so using realloc after new seems like a bad idea.You should be going for vector as a better approach. You can resize vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no `realloc` in C++ (due to the fact that memory might hold non-trivially constructed or just non-copyable objects). Either allocate new buffer and copy or learn to use `std::vector` or `std::stack` that would do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider switching from the hand-crafted dynamic array to a vector a good first choice.

As far as whether the vector should contain objects directly, or contain pointers to the actual objects, there isn't a single definitive answer -- it depends on a number of factors.

The single biggest factor is whether these are what I'd call "entity" objects -- ones for which copying makes no sense. A classic case in point would be something like an iostream or a network connection. There's generally no logical way to copy or assign an object like this. If that's the sort of object you're dealing with, you're pretty much stuck storing pointers.

If, however, you're dealing with what are generally (loosely) defined as "value objects", copying and assigning will be fine, and storing the objects directly in the vector will be fine. With objects like this, the primary reason to store pointers instead would be that a vector can/will copy objects around when it has to expand the memory to make room for more objects. If your objects are so large and expensive to copy that this is unacceptable, then you might want to store something pointer-like in the vector to get cheap copying and assignment. Chances are that will *not* be a raw pointer though -- it'll probably be some sort of smart pointer object that provide more value-like semantics so most other code can treat the object as being a simple value, and the details of its expensive operations and such can remain hidden.

Answer (score -1):

There is no C++ equivalent of realloc().

Best use:

```
char* new_tmp = new (char*)[mtmp];
for (int n=0;n<min(mtmp,oldSize);n++) new_tmp[n] = tmp[n];
delete [] tmp;  // free up tmp
tmp = new_tmp;
```

The error you are getting is because C++ is less lenient with implicit type casting.

Comment: Not the best use - the idea of `realloc` is to retain memory content.

Comment: If you insist on doing manual memory allocation, you should allocate the new memory, then copy the contents to the newly allocated memory. Only after both those succeed should you delete the old memory.