# Reallocating memory of a C++ array.

Tags: c++, new-operator, realloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you `realloc` in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482941/how-do-you-realloc-in-c)

I know that C++ arrays can be reallocated (expanded) using `realloc()` if memory has been allocated via `malloc()` or `calloc()`. My question is, how can I expand an array in C++ whose memory has been allocated via the `new` operator?

Comment: malloc/realloc are C library calls - although they can be used in C++ they should in general be avoided since C++ has more robust ways of dealing with dynamic arrays etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't - that's why in C++ you use `std::vector<>`.

If you wanted to do this, you'd have to allocate a new array (via `new`), then copy the old items across (`std::copy` for example), then `delete[]` the previous array.

Just use `std::vector` - let it do all that stuff for you...

Comment: "then copy the old items" - or move them.

Answer (score 6):

In general C++ arrays cannot be reallocated with `realloc`, even if the storage was allocated with `malloc`. `malloc` doesn't give you arrays. It gives pointers to usable storage. There's a subtle difference here.

For POD types, there's little difference between usable storage and actual objects. But for non-POD types, usable storage and objects are totally different things.

`realloc` gives you a larger portion of usable storage. It manipulates *storage* not *objects*. That may work fine for POD types, but for other types it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: So technically is it possible to expand an array using `realloc()` that was allocated using `calloc()` or is `realloc()` possible only if memory has been allocated via `malloc()` ?

Comment: @amalantony Oh, the same goes for `calloc`. The problem is with `realloc` itself. It doesn't care for objects, only storage.

Comment: @amal: the difference between `malloc` and `calloc` is completely irrelevant to what Martinho is saying here. You can't `realloc` non-POD objects, because you can't copy them byte-by-byte, and that's all `realloc` is defined to do. Even in C, if your objects contain pointers into themselves or each other then you can't `realloc` them because the addresses would no longer be correct. C++ just adds the caveat that for non-POD classes, the implementation might insert things like that of its own accord.

Answer (score 0):

Use `::std::vector`.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482941/how-do-you-realloc-in-c) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869211/replacing-realloc-c-c) for more details.