# Unzip buffer with large data length is crashing

Tags: c++, buffer, zlib, inflate, compression

This is the function I am using to unzip buffer.

```
string unzipBuffer(size_t decryptedLength, unsigned char * decryptedData)
{
    z_stream stream;
    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.avail_in = decryptedLength;
    stream.next_in = (Bytef *)decryptedData;
    stream.total_out = 0;
    stream.avail_out = 0;
    size_t dataLength = decryptedLength* 1.5;
    char c[dataLength];

    if (inflateInit2(&stream, 47) == Z_OK)
    {
        int status = Z_OK;
        while (status == Z_OK)
        {
            if (stream.total_out >= dataLength)
            {
                dataLength += decryptedLength * 0.5;
            }

            stream.next_out = (Bytef *)c + stream.total_out;

            stream.avail_out = (uint)(dataLength - stream.total_out);

            status = inflate (&stream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);

        }
        if (inflateEnd(&stream) == Z_OK)
        {
            if (status == Z_STREAM_END)
            {
                dataLength = stream.total_out;
            }
        }
    }
    std::string decryptedContentStr(c, c + dataLength);
    return decryptedContentStr;
}
```

And it was working fine until today when I realized that it crashes with large data buffer (Ex: decryptedLength: 342792) on this line:

```
status = inflate (&stream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
```

after one or two iterations. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Maybe you should tell exactly how it crashed. BTW - could this be a stack overflow issue? `char c[dataLength];` is approx. 600.000 chars.

Comment: Unzipping is not decrypting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code generally works correctly, but fails for large data sets, then this could be due to a stack overflow as indicated by @StillLearning in his comment.

A usual (default) stack size is 1 MB. When your `decryptedLength` is 342,792, then you try to allocate 514,188 byte in the following line:

```
char c[dataLength];
```

Together with other allocations in your code (and finally in the `inflate()` function), this might already be too much. To overcome this problem, you should allocate the memory dynamically:

```
char* c = new char[dataLength];
```

If you so this, then please do not forget to release the allocated memory at the end of your `unzipBuffer()` function:

```
delete[] c;
```

If you forget to delete the allocated memory, then you will have a memory leak.

In case this doesn't (fully) solve your problem, you should do it anyway, because for even larger data sets your code will break for sure due to the limited size of the stack.

---

In case you need to "reallocate" your dynamically allocated buffer in your `while()` loop, then please take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9586345/2675154). Basically you need to use a combination of `new`, `std::copy`, and `delete[]`. However, it would be more appropriate if your exchange your `char` array with a `std::vector<char>` or even `std::vector<Bytef>`. Then you would be able enlarge your buffer easily by using the `resize()` function. You can directly access the buffer of a `vector` by using `&my_vector[0]` in order to assign it to `stream.next_out`.

Comment: thanks for the help, but the problem persists. And thanks for the advice, I will keep allocating the memory dynamically.

Comment: You are welcome! Please also take a look at the answer by @MarkAdler. He raises a point that also made me suspicious. I didn't include it, because I don't exactly know how the zlib works. Just try it with 3 instead of 1.5 times. If it works, then you need to dynamically reallocate your buffer in order to enlarge it.

Comment: @Grace: I added some explanation on the "reallocation" issue to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the great help, I'll change my code to meet your explanation and let you know once done

Comment: Works very well. Thanks :D

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 1):

`c` is not going to get bigger just because you increase `datalength`.  You are probably overwriting past the end of `c` because your initial guess of 1.5 times the compressed size was wrong, causing the fault.

(It might be a stack overflow as suggested in another answer here, but I think that 8 MB stack allocations are common nowadays.)