# How to reallocate dyanmic array when using new and delete C++ without using realloc?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, memcpy, realloc

So in C++, I read that C `realloc(&dest, &source, nbytes)` is bad because it doesn't work with new and delete.

So how to reallocate data correctly in C++? Assume I have:

```
int* a = new int[100];
```

But I wish to resize it to int[200]. The simplest way I think of is:

```
int* old = a;
int* newPos = new int[200];
memcpy(newPos, a, sizeof(int)*100);
a = newPos;
delete[] old;
```

Is there a simpler way? Thank you

Comment: Use [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), probably `std::vector`, in your case `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Yes I know that containers are correct in this case. But specifically, is there anyway to realloc in C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reallocating memory of a C++ array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586345/reallocating-memory-of-a-c-array)

Comment: And the *compiler* usually knows about standard containers. BTW, even in C, `realloc`  is often incorrectly used (e.g. for failure cases). So please use containers,  or give up C++

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::copy`, not memcpy:

```
std::copy(old, old+100, newPos);
```

but in general, you should avoid using `new` and `delete` directly and instead use standard containers (probably `std::vector<int>` in your case) which deal with all of this for you when you call their `resize` method.